# Upload Documents from ASP.Net to Sharepoint Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, httpwebrequest, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to upload files from ASP.Net to Sharepoint (In-order to preserve TimeStamp I'm using this way)

The following is my code

```
    protected void UploadFileToSharePoint(string UploadedFilePath, string SharePointPath)
    {
        WebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            string SUrl = "http://MysharepointPath/Folder";

            //WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(SharePointPath);

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(SUrl);

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username,password );

            //request.Method = "PUT";

            request.Method = "POST";

            FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead(UploadedFilePath);
            string fileName = fStream.Name.Substring(3);
            byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
            fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);

            fStream.Close();

            request.ContentLength = 0;

            //Custom code
            using (WebClient uploader = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    uploader.UploadFile(new Uri(SUrl), UploadedFilePath);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
            response = request.GetResponse();
        }
 }
```

When i try to run the code in debug mode it throws exception

> "remote server returned an error 401 unauthorized"

Comment: does your application pool identity (the account your application runs under) have read/write permission to the destination folder?

Comment: Yes it's having the Read/Write Permission

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by '(In-order to preserve TimeStamp I'm using this way)'? the timestamp on the uploaded document in SharePoint's going to be the date the document was added to the SharePoint document library

The error 401 (Unauthorized), indicates that the client must first authenticate itself, so can you use Fiddler to validate if you're authenticating in the SharePoint server?

Are you using SharePoint Online or OnPremises?.

There are a few samples in codeplex for what you're trying to accomplish, please review this link for more information...
 http://spfileupload.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Get-SPScripts.Copy-FilesToSP.ps1